# Override @param doc on nelmio api doc

Tags: rest, api, symfony, nelmioapidocbundle

I have a REST controller using the ParamConverter Symfony's service, using nelmio api doc annotation :

```
<?php

    /**
     * @param Plan $plan The plan id
     *
     * @ApiDoc(
     *  description="Returns plan details",
     *  output={
     *      "class"="AppBundle\Entity\Plan",
     *      "groups"={"details"}
     *  }
     * )
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getAction(Plan $plan) // [...]
```

The api doc is correctly rendered but show a `Plan` requirement type:

[image]

I want to rename my parameter to `plan_id` and specify the `integer` type.

So I tried with `requirements` options, like this:

```
<?php

    /**
     * @param Plan $plan The plan id
     *
     * @ApiDoc(
     *  description="Returns plan details",
     *  requirements={
     *      {
     *          "name"="plan_id",
     *          "dataType"="integer",
     *          "requirement"="\d+",
     *          "description"="The plan's id"
     *      }
     *  },
     *  output={
     *      "class"="AppBundle\Entity\Plan",
     *      "groups"={"details"}
     *  }
     * )
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getAction(Plan $plan) // [...]
```

But now it's showing me both parameters:

[image]

What is the best and proper method to override or remove `@param` tag from api doc? Without remove it form comment doc of course...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Strange, refering to this issue: https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/issues/477 you shouldn't have this behavior, which version do you use?

Comment: The latest dev-master checkout.

Comment: It's a bit old, but the two variable names have to be the same, either plan or plan_id.